# API string returning no value

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I'm trying to fetch an API in kotlin with volley, but once I try to get the string from the object, I get nothing returned: **W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for burned**

**This is the API:**

```
"requested_information": [
    {
      "level": 1,
      "character": "一",
      "kana": "いち",
      "meaning": "one",
      "user_specific": {
        "srs": "burned",
        "srs_numeric": 9,
        "unlocked_date": 1464639834,
        "available_date": 0,
        "burned": true,
```

```
try {
                    val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("requested_information")

                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

                        // Append character to textView here
                        val cha = jsonObject.getString("character")
                        val burn = jsonObject.getString("user_specific")
                        val burn2: Boolean = jsonObject.getBoolean("burned")
```

Comment: You're getting "user_specific" as a String instead of a Json object and storing it in a variable which you don't use. You're then trying to get "burned" from the main object instead of user_specific. Get user_specific as an object and then burned from that new object.

Comment: How could I create an Authorization header with Kotlin?